# Trivial Edit to Answer that Doesn't Effect Outcome

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718125/using-concatenate-in-the-validation-source-field-to-refer-to-a-named-table/28718219#28718219) with a working solution. The answer was edited by the OP to include some extra parenthesis that are not required and make no difference to the outcome of the question.

I've no issue with others editing an answer of mine to amend a mistake but in this case there was no mistake. Also the edit was [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7156748) by three users who appear to not regularly get involved in the tags in question.

What should I do in this case? Edit the answer back to the original and post a quick comment? Leave it as is? I'm not too concerned about this example as the edit still technically works but more as a what if the amendment caused the formula to not function and the fact that it was approved?

Comment: These parentheses are indeed superfluous and make the code harder to read and validate. I rolled that edit back.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks, is it best to post here for future reference, is it best just to post here?

Comment: it's missing a closing bracket though, 3 opened and only 2 closed.

Comment: @Tanner, you're right, I should get my eyes checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're welcome to roll back any edit to any of your posts that you felt did not actually improve it, and *possibly* made it worse. Just avoid getting into an edit war - involve a moderator right away if it looks like that's what is going to happen. Editors should respect your intent and voice as an author.

You can also leave a comment telling whoever made the edit that you had things the way that they were quite deliberately, and there's no need to [insert whatever they added here].

There's *usually* nothing but the best intentions behind these sorts of edits, so it's usually nothing but a matter of rolling it back. If it gets out of hand, involve a mod. That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I had no particular issue with the edit and to be fair as @Tanner pointed out it did actually fix the code in some way. Will get my eyes checked in future thanks.

Comment: The problem is that if you leave a comment to the editor, they do not get notified. :/